# Exportar informações do processo para um .txt

Tags: python, txt, exportação

Estou com um problema em exportar as informações que o meu processo esta gerando.
Atualmente eu copio tudo que esta no meu **print** e colo em um arquivo txt, mas gostaria de tirar este processo manual do meu projeto.

Queria saber se é possível eu inserir diretamente os valores gerados em um **.txt** na minha area de trabalho por exemplo. **No caso eu chamei ele no código de test.txt**

Código:

```
 f = open(r"C:\Users\guilgig\Desktop\test.txt", "w")
with open(r'C:\Users\guilgig\Desktop\Respostas.txt') as stream:
    for line in stream:
        for word in ['(ANUIDADE', 
'alta,,anuidade', 
'ANUID', 
'ANUIDA', 
'ANUIDAD', 
'ANUIDADE', 
'ANUIDADE)', 
'anuidade,', 
'anuidade,vcs', 
'anuidade.', 
'ANUIDADES', 
'ANUIDADR6', 
'POUCOS(EMPRESARIOS']:
            if word.lower() in line.lower():
                print(line.strip(), '¬', word)
          
                break
```

Comment: O que exatamente este código deveria fazer?

Comment: Gigle, voce por ventura teria alguma amostra do arquivo de entrada, e alguma amostra do arquivo de saida? Assim podemos compreender quais sao as entradas e saidas esperadas.

Comment: Este projeto procuro dentro do texto esta lista de palavras.
o projeto em si funciona, mas queria fazer o que aparece dentro do PRINT no log... fazer isto dentro de um .txt

me desculpem, esqueci do arquivo que eu coloco.
mas ele contem o seguinte texto:

2701¬ SEMPRE QUE PRECISEI FUI ATENDIDO COM ATENAO
6913¬ conhecimento
11607¬ Atendimento noturno. atencioso e competente !
13286¬ OTIMO ATENDIMENTO
14747¬ E pq eu estou satisfeito . sendo Client

Answer (score -1):

Consegui fazer esta primeira parte, agora estou com um problema de quebra de linhas, deveria quebrar a cada variável feita, mas vem tudo na mesma linha.

Resposta:

```
     f = open(r"C:\Users\guilgig\Desktop\test.txt", "w")
with open(r'C:\Users\guilgig\Desktop\Respostas.txt') as stream:
    for line in stream:
        for word in ['(ANUIDADE', 
'alta,,anuidade', 
'ANUID', 
'ANUIDA', 
'ANUIDAD', 
'ANUIDADE', 
'ANUIDADE)', 
'anuidade,', 
'anuidade,vcs', 
'anuidade.', 
'ANUIDADES', 
'ANUIDADR6', 
'POUCOS(EMPRESARIOS']:
            if word.lower() in line.lower():
                
              a = (line.strip(), '¬', word +'\n')
              
              arquivo.write(str(a))
              break
arquivo.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode concatenar o seu texto da seguinte maneira:

```
a = '%s%s%s\n' % (line.strip(), '¬', word)
```

Também sugiro que mova a atribuição da lista de words para fora do loop, para melhorar a performance e a legibilidade do seu código.

O código completo ficaria assim:

```
words = ['(ANUIDADE', 
        'alta,,anuidade', 
        'ANUID', 
        'ANUIDA', 
        'ANUIDAD', 
        'ANUIDADE', 
        'ANUIDADE)', 
        'anuidade,', 
        'anuidade,vcs', 
        'anuidade.', 
        'ANUIDADES', 
        'ANUIDADR6', 
        'POUCOS(EMPRESARIOS']

f = open(r"C:\Users\guilgig\Desktop\test.txt", "w")
with open(r"C:\Users\guilgig\Desktop\Respostas.txt") as stream:
    for line in stream:
        for word in words:
            if word.lower() in line.lower():
                a = '%s%s%s\n' % (line.strip(), '¬', word)
                arquivo.write(a)
                break
arquivo.close()
```